# Azure B2C SingleLogoutService location

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need to provide IdP (SAML 2.0) the *SingleLogoutService Location* of our Azure B2C tenant, i.e., something like

```
<md:EntityDescriptor …
  <md:SPSSODescriptor …
    <md:SingleLogoutService 
          Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
          Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT>.onmicrosoft.com/saml2" />
```

What would that Location be? I was able to figure out the ACS which is

```
<md:AssertionConsumerService 
Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<TENANT>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer"
index="1" isDefault="true"/>
```

I assume the Single Logout Service is something similar but cannot find any reference what it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Azure AD B2C metadata at:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenant>/<policy>/samlp/metadata`

The Single Logout service location should be:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenant>/<policy>/samlp/sso/logout`

Comment: Looks like I need to add "idptp" parameter to get metadata, like ?idtp=<PROFILENAME>, without it, it's just responding with server error.